# Выражение "заешь меня короста"

Tags: этимология, фразеология, выбор-слов

**Ах! Заешь меня короста!**
Что надумал? Ну и ну -
Допустить врага в страну!

*Слова воеводы из м/ф "Сказка о золотом петушке"*

---

Всему стараюсь время уделять, непросто...
Да наплевать! **И хоть заешь меня короста**...

*Л. Панасенко*

---

...Лук не спортивный, а средневековый, с меньшим натяжением, правда. Тупой пехотинец, **заешь меня короста!**

*В. С. Устинов*,  *журнал "Самиздат"*

---

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим знанием или мнением по поводу возникновения, значения и употребления выражения.

Comment: Вам помочь сделать ссылки кликабельные? Или вы принципиально их не признаете?

Answer (score 3):

Очень мало есть на свете идиом, фразеологизмов, история чьего происхождения дошла до наших дней. Разве что действительно "авторские", то есть однажды впервые употреблённые лицом пишущим и ушедшие "в народ".

Допускаю, что с Пушкина - родоначальника современного русского языка - всё и началось, он первый употребил именно этот порядок слов, которые позднее стали широкоупотребительными, превратившись в идиому, - ***заешь меня короста.***

По смыслу полными синонимами будут ***разрази меня гром*** или ***чтоб мне провалиться на этом месте*** (можно и ещё поискать...).

А значение слова "короста" (здесь), думается, не "гнойные струпья на коже" (следствие чесотки), а сама чесотка, без ненужной детализации.

***Чтоб мне сдохнуть под забором!***

> разрази меня гром
>
> нареч, кол-во синонимов: 4 • гадом буду (27) • зуб
> даю (66) • мамой клянусь (39) • чтоб я жил на одну зарплату (6)

Comment: А где такое у Пушкина, если не секрет? В четырехтомном "Словаре языка Пушкина" даже слова *"короста"* нет. http://imwerden.de/pdf/slovar_yazyka_pushkina_tom1_2000_text.pdf

Comment: Морковушкин, не искала я у Нашего Всего - поверила сценаристу! )))

Comment: Кому поверили???

Comment: Морковушкмн, трёх знаков вопроса не бывает как класса, только три!!! Поверила, что мульт снят по тексту сказки...

Comment: Если бы выражение принадлежало перу Александра Сергеевича, я бы ТАК и указала...  А у меня четко написано: Слова воеводы из м/ф "Сказка о золотом петушке". Услышала в мультике. Стало интересно - откуда взялось? Насколько современно и употребимо?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я тоже весьма удивился подобному домысливанию. Но отвечать уже не хотелось. ---  *Насколько современно и употребимо?* - ну этого-то просто не было в вопросе. Не очень современно и не очень употребимо. Но встречается.

Comment: Я наивно подумала, что, если цитаты современные, то будет понятно и в вопросе - "употребление выражения".   P.S. Кликабельные ссылки - это моя головная боль. Ваш адрес я помню.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу скажу, что исчерпывающего ответа у меня нету, я даже не хотел отвечать, но заставило несогласие с первым ответом.

> Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим знанием или мнением по поводу
>   возникновения, значения и употребления выражения.

Я с конца начну. Со "значения и употребления". Употребление, совершенно очевидно, - некая клятва или ручательство, как и во всех случаях, даваемых как синонимы. Значение - сокращение от "разрази меня короста, если ошибаюсь (вру)". Значение всего выражения - выражение через клятву удивления, восторга, радости, неожиданности. Туи спорить не о чем.

А вот происхождение... Может, конечно, и Пушкин (не буду говорить наверняка, пока не увижу подобное у Пушкина), но вряд ли он первый. С чего бы ему придумывать-то столь вычурное выражение с нуля? Нет, подобные клятвы были вполне популярны в народном языке со времен едва ли не Перуновых ("разрази меня гром" - явная отсылка к Перуну-Громовежцу, который мог бы и покарать за неправду). Или там "ешь меня раки", "чтоб мне на месте провалиться" - да и все подобные. Могло использоваться либо в сочетании с какой-то инфомацией непосредственно, либо в ответ на "поклянись"/"побожись". Вот это "побожись", пожалуй, лучше всего передают смысл.

Так что я вижу "заешь меня короста" - вполне осмысленным, в ряду прочих подобных.

Слово "заешь" = замучь, порази. А "короста", думаю, здесь как раз прямое и конкретное, нет необходимости его как-то абстрагировать от основного значения. В украинском языке это значение короста = чесотка сохранилась, но в русском-то это именно струпья. Впрочем, не принципиально.

Но вот конкретику происхождения я не назову.